# smaller apk size when built with VS Code

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code, apk

Greeting. I am new to flutter, and developing using VS Code on Windows 10. Both flutter and VS code are of latest versions.

Lately, I noticed something rather strange. When I built the Android apk using the flutter CLI (flutter build apk --debug / --release), the output apk seems to always be about 10MB+ larger compared to those built within VS Code (through the debug & release configurations in launch.json).

Here's the sample apk size built in a basic flutter project created by 'flutter create':

> Builds by VS Code:
> -rw-r--r-- 1 teeka 197609 57557589 Aug  8 14:45 ./build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk
> -rw-r--r-- 1 teeka 197609  6586727 Aug  8 14:43 ./build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-release.apk
>
> Builds by 'flutter build apk':
> -rw-r--r-- 1 teeka 197609 70762755 Aug  8 14:45 ./build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk
> -rw-r--r-- 1 teeka 197609 16802483 Aug  8 14:47 ./build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-release.apk

Appreciate if anyone can help offer some clarification on the discrepancy. Thanks in advance.

Naturally, we all like a smaller APK size, but I wondering if there's any string attached.

Thanks.

Comment: https://docs.flutter.dev/testing/build-modes. Refer this for better understanding, In release mode code minification is done and hence the app size is small . In debug mode, code minification is not done & results in a relatively larger size

Comment: Yes it's strange, can you put your `launch.json` please

Comment: @YannisSauzeau posted below as requested.

Comment: @Prashant my question is on the size differences between two same target build, not between debug or release build.

Comment: @Pauld'Poulpe Ok I understand now, the difference is because your `launch.json` file launch the command `flutter run` instead of `flutter build`. Try manually `flutter run` and normally your apk will have the same size :)

Comment: Source: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/96650

Comment: @YannisSauzeau it's clear to me now. Very grateful for your help to clarify this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the content of launch.json:

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "flutter_new_project",
        "request": "launch",
        "type": "dart"
    },
    {
        "name": "flutter_new_project (debug mode)",
        "request": "launch",
        "type": "dart",
        "flutterMode": "debug"
    },
    {
        "name": "flutter_new_project (release mode)",
        "request": "launch",
        "type": "dart",
        "flutterMode": "release"
    }
]
```

}